# No puedo borrar elementos con Iterator()

Tags: java

actualmente tengo una clase para eliminar un objeto abstracto `Publicacion`, por tanto, no instanciable, con dos objetos hijo: `Disco` y `Libro`.

Tengo que hacer un método para eliminar Publicaciones siempre que coincidan con el título pasado por parámetro, y me piden que sea mediante la clase iterator.

Así es como tengo formulada dicha clase:

```
private LinkedHashSet<Publicacion> disco;

public void delPubli(String titulo){
        Iterator<Publicacion> it = disco.iterator();
        
        while(it.hasNext()){
            
            if(it.next() instanceof Disco){
                Disco d = (Disco)it.next();

                if(d.getTitulo().equalsIgnoreCase(titulo)){
                    //disco.remove(it.next());
                    disco.remove(d);
                    System.out.println("Disco eliminado");
                }
                
            } else if (it.next() instanceof Libro){
                Libro l = (Libro)it.next();

                if(l.getTitulo().equalsIgnoreCase(titulo)){
                    //disco.remove(it.next());
                    disco.remove(l);
                    System.out.println("Libro eliminado");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Tengo puestos los filtros por objetos para que pueda eliminar tanto Discos como Libros.
Hago el cast al objeto correspondiente, asigno al objeto creado momentáneamente el valor del it actual, y si coincide el título de la Publicacion como el pasado por parámetro, aunque sea ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas, debería eliminarlo.

Pero no consigo hacer que se elimine de ninguna forma, salta este error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:758)
at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:778)
at Ex5.Tienda.delPubli(Tienda.java:31)
at Ex5.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Asumo que sea un problema del propio it, asumo que el método .next(). Pero sinceramente estoy bastante perdido.

¿Cómo podría implementarlo correctamente?, porque hasta ahora lo había hecho siempre con el foreach, el cual nunca me da problemas, pero ya quiero aprender a hacerlo así.

Gracias de antebrazo.

---

**[EDIT]**

El nuevo error que me da con la solución del amigo @Lobos

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(LinkedHashMap.java:756) at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(LinkedHashMap.java:778) at Ex5.Tienda.delPubli(Tienda.java:55) at Ex5.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

---

Vale, ya está, tenía que hacer la eliminación a través del it.

```
if(l.getTitulo().equalsIgnoreCase(titulo)){
                    it.remove();
                    System.out.println("Libro eliminado");
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás saltando elementos, cada vez que llamas a `next()` el puntero avanza una casilla por eso llegas al error `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

Primero guarda el elemento en una variable y luego la usas en las condiciones.

```
public void delPubli(String titulo){
        Iterator<Publicacion> it = disco.iterator();
        
        while(it.hasNext()){
            Object element = it.next();
            if(element instanceof Disco){
                Disco d = (Disco)element;

                if(d.getTitulo().equalsIgnoreCase(titulo)){
                    //disco.remove(it.next());
                    disco.remove(d);
                    System.out.println("Disco eliminado");
                }
                
            } else if (element instanceof Libro){
                Libro l = (Libro)element;

                if(l.getTitulo().equalsIgnoreCase(titulo)){
                    disco.remove(l);
                    System.out.println("Libro eliminado");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Edité la pregunta al final del todo. Parece que al eliminar el objeto se rompe el bucle de alguna manera. Entiendo que sea porque, según he leído por ahí,  iterator no pueda verificar la integridad de los datos si se le añaden o quitan elementos. Pero entonces ¿cómo puedo hacerlo con ese bucle?